# How to print non zero elements of the matrix containing zero elements and non-zero elements both?

Tags: matrix

A matrix with both non-zero and zero elements is given. I want to print only the non-zero elements of the matrix. What is syntax that have to be used for this?

matr2 = Table[FortranForm[matrixx[[i, j]]], {i, 12}, {j, 12}];
matr3 = ExportString[
  Flatten@Table[
    "matrix(" <> ToString[i] <> "," <> ToString[j] <> ") = " <> 
     ToString[matr2[[i, j]]], {i, Length[matr2]}, {j, 
     Length[matr2[[1]]]}], "Table"]
CopyToClipboard[matr3]

This commnand prints the data of matrix matr2 as matrix(1,1)=a11 element of matr2. So my question is related to this that is if i want to print only the non-zero elements of matr2? what syntax should i have to added in this?

Comment: You can use `DeleteCases[#, 0] & /@ mat`.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps this example

matrix = RandomInteger[{0, 2}, {3, 3}];
   matrix // MatrixForm

which displays thiis

```
0 0 2
1 0 2
0 0 1
```

Then this

```
matrix /. v_ /; v == 0 -> "" // MatrixForm
```

which displays this

```
    2
1   2
    1
```

EDIT/Append

I saw you revised your question after I posted the above. Perhaps you can adapt this:

```
StringJoin[Flatten[Table[
  If[matrixx[[i, j]] == 0, "", "matrix("<>ToString[i]<>","<>ToString[j]<>") = " <> 
    ToString[matrixx[[i, j]]]<>"\n"], {i, Length[matrixx]}, {j, Length[matrixx[[1]]]}]]]
```

Once you have turned something into a *Form, whether MatrixForm or FortranForm or *Form, that might make it pretty to look at but you often can't do any further calculations with that until you strip off the *Form and most new users are not aware of this or understand how to do this.

Comment: please take a look at my edited question.

Comment: My answer revised to more closely match your question revised.

Comment: matrixx = Table[Subscript[m, i, j], {i, 9}, {j, 9}]   matrixx[[1 ;; 1, 1 ;; 9]] = 0    i have used above syntax written by you to check it on simple problem. But I think it is not working. You should look at this example too. it should print all the remaining rows of matrixx.

Comment: So use === instead of ==.
matrixx = Table[Subscript[m, i, j], {i, 9}, {j, 9}];
matrixx[[1 ;; 1, 1 ;; 9]] = 0;
StringJoin[Flatten[Table[If[matrixx[[i, j]] === 0, "", "matrix(" <> ToString[i] <> "," <> ToString[j] <> ") = " <> ToString[matrixx[[i, j]]] <> "\n"], {i, Length[matrixx]}, {j, Length[matrixx[[1]]]}]]] but I urge you to not use subscripts, no matter how desperately you believe you must use subscripts.

Comment: Thanks. Anyways subscript I mentioned was just for example. In my work, I am not using it. I know the problem I will face with that. Thanks anyways.